# How to determine the best cutoff for an easy question

Tags: r, statistics

Here is the outline of my data. There are 500 students. Each student has final grade for math, physics, chemistry, music, history. The range of the final grade for each subject is from 0 to 100.  For each subject, if student's grade is below a cutoff, then the student will fail this subject. However, the teacher of each subject may change a few students (less than 5%) assessment from fail to pass due to their good performance for class activity. If a student fail any subject, then the overall assessment is supposed to be fail. If a student pass all 5 subjects, then the overall assessment is pass.

Now suppose the cutoffs for math, physics, chemistry, music, history are 45, 45, 45, 60, 60, respectively. Then we will have the demo table below. The second student passed the history due to the history teacher is satisfied with his class performance.

```
ID    math    physics   chemistry   music   history overall_assessment

1       95    96   70 65 75 pass

2       46    61  72 86 59 pass

3       55    32 21 95 96 fail
```

Now my question is that if I have the table above, how can I know the cutoff for each subject? I have the data below in R.

```
set.seed(1)
math <-  sample(30:100, 500, replace=T)
physics <- sample(30:100, 500, replace=T)
chemistry<- sample(30:100, 500, replace=T)
music<- sample(30:100, 500, replace=T)
history<- sample(60:100, 500, replace=T)
grade <- as.data.frame(cbind(math,physics,chemistry,music,history))
grade$assess <- ifelse(grade$math > 45 & grade$physics >55 & grade$chemistry > 60 & grade$music > 50 & grade$history > 80, "pass","fail")
grade$ID <- seq(1,500,1)
change_grade <- sample(1:500, 25, replace=F)
grade$assess[grade$ID %in% change_grade] <- "pass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is randomness in who is selected to pass for good activity, it is not possible to find the exact cutoff values. But we can find upper and lower bounds for the cutoff. Note that I slightly adjust the data generation, but you can change it and confirm this method gives correct bounds no matter the true cutoffs.

```r
library(tidyverse)
n <- 500
prop <- 0.05

set.seed(1)
math <-  sample(30:100, n, replace = T)
physics <- sample(30:100, n, replace = T)
chemistry <- sample(30:100, n, replace = T)
music <- sample(30:100, n, replace = T)
history <- sample(30:100, n, replace = T)
grade <- 
  as.data.frame(cbind(math, physics, chemistry, music, history))
grade$assess <- ifelse(
  grade$math >= 45 &
    grade$physics >= 45 &
    grade$chemistry >= 45 &
    grade$music >= 60 &
    grade$history >= 60,
  "pass", "fail")
grade$ID <- seq(1, n, 1)
change_grade <- sample(1:n, n * prop, replace = F)
grade$assess[grade$ID %in% change_grade] <- "pass"
grade$assess <- factor(grade$assess)
```

To find the upper bound for a subject, we will consider all individuals who passed the assessment, and look at their grades in that subject. We know that at most 25 individuals were granted an exception for that subject (n * proportion of exceptions), so the grade of the 26th worst individual is an upper bound for the cutoff score.

```r
# upper bound
get_upper_bound <- function(var, n, prop) {
  var <- var[order(var)]
  var[ceiling(n * prop) + 1]
}
upper_bound <- grade %>%
  subset(assess == "pass") %>%
  summarise(
    math = get_upper_bound(math, n = n, prop = prop),
    physics = get_upper_bound(physics, n = n, prop = prop),
    chemistry = get_upper_bound(chemistry, n = n, prop = prop),
    music = get_upper_bound(music, n = n, prop = prop),
    history = get_upper_bound(history, n = n, prop = prop))
upper_bound
#>   math physics chemistry music history
#> 1   57      53        58    68      67
```

Having now found an upper bound, we can look at the lower bounds. Consider all individuals who passed Math, Physics, Chemistry, and Music by achieving at least the upper bound in those subjects, but who also failed the assessment. Then we know that they must have failed the History subject. Looking at the maximum History grade in those students gives us a lower bound for the cutoff score for History. We can apply this for all different subjects.

This code is inelegant, but I believe it works.

```r
# lower bound
get_lower_bound <- function(varnum, data, upper_bound) {
  varnames = c("math", "physics", "chemistry", "music", "history")
  vars_using <- c(1:5)
  vars_using <- vars_using[-varnum]
  indexes <- rep(TRUE, nrow(data))
  for (i in vars_using) {
    indexes <-
      indexes & (data[, varnames[i]] >= as.numeric(upper_bound[i]))
  }
  indexes <- indexes & (data$assess == "fail")
  ifelse(is.finite(max(data[indexes, varnum])),
         max(data[indexes, varnum]) + 1,
         min(data[, varnum]))
}
lower_bound <- data.frame(
  "math" = get_lower_bound(1, grade, upper_bound),
  "physics" = get_lower_bound(2, grade, upper_bound),
  "chemistry" = get_lower_bound(3, grade, upper_bound),
  "music" = get_lower_bound(4, grade, upper_bound),
  "history" = get_lower_bound(5, grade, upper_bound))
lower_bound
#>   math physics chemistry music history
#> 1   45      44        45    58      60
```

Then the final bounds for the cutoff scores are:

```r
rbind("lower" = lower_bound,
      "upper" = upper_bound)
#>       math physics chemistry music history
#> lower   45      44        45    58      60
#> upper   57      53        58    68      67
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that by increasing `n` and decreasing `prop`, eventually the lower bound and upper bound are equal, and we have found the cutoff score exactly.